# Why Kotlin Compose function dont recompose

Tags: android, kotlin, compose-recomposition, android-compose

In the process of debugging, I noticed something that I cannot explain to myself. Here is my example

```
Column {
       var text by remember {
               mutableStateOf("")
        }

        TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
        Image(
              painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mypos_world_white),
              contentDescription = null
        )
}
```

Everything is clear here, we enter the text, and we get a recomposition of both the text of the field and the picture, as painterResource is [marked as unstable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/optimization).

[Layout Inscpector Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVsUj.png)

Ffter i bring the picture into a separate function the behavior changes

```
//call site
Column {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
    ImageFunction()
}

@Composable
fun ImageFunction() {
    Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mypos_world_white),
            contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

[Layout Inscpector Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWazM.png)
Now recomposition is skipped.

Shuld we bring all unstable components, like Images, out of main scope, and why this works like this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple possible reasons:

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/16rsmj5/did_you_know_that_painter_is_not_stable_and/ <- painter resource may not be stable (yet) so it may be worth to export the image to an external function that takes in a drawableResource as a parameter (HOWEVER, you may use the ImageVector which seems to be already marked as immutable, see [this](https://engineering.teknasyon.com/reduce-recomposition-for-images-icons-in-jetpack-compose-8d2dd3bfa933))
2. the `Image` Composable is part of the same scope as the `TextField`. Since they share the same scope, any change in one will cause the other to recompose. This is because the `Image` Composable is marked as unstable (painterResource), so it triggers a recomposition whenever its value changes.